# Egit functions not working properly

Tags: eclipse-plugin, egit

I have few questions about EGIT plugin for eclipse.
I have downloaded code in the repository from github site with EGIT software.
But have the following questions

1. I modified the code and used replacewith or synchronize the code and try to use overwrite the changed code. I still see the "<" on the same file and if i do a comparewith or synchronize again.. i see the same file displayed but without the content. So i am wondering that when overwrite/replacewith works then why the file pops up with comparewith or synchronize.
2. What should i do to get the latest code. I know pull works but where does the pull gets the files from.. from the git branch or the local workspace repo.

Awaiting your reply.. really confused.

Thanks

Comment: REally want to fix this problem.. can anybody help

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question 1, git needs to rescan the workspace in order to identify the status against the repository (what was changed etc.). If your repository has a large number of files this may take a while. Do you see a git job running in the background (you can see a progress bar in the bottom right corner)?

As for question 2, when you clone the github repository, your local repository maintains a refrence to the remote github repository, and that's where you pull from.

Comment: Question 1 No the Github job is not running in the back.. I wait for the job to get over but still the > sign popsup.. Its driving me crazy.. When we do replacewith/synchronize overwrite, does github overwrites the file from the remote repo version or is the local repo version?

Question 2 If the pull is from the local reference.. What is the way to get the latest from the remote repo directly..I need that to happen

Comment: Also i am not sure how github helps to compare the local file to remote location version of the file.. I hardly can see the new changes..All installations seem to be good as i can import using egit

Comment: 1. Synchronize uses the local repository. 2. git pull updates you local repository with the changes in the remote repository.

Comment: Oh k so what do i need to do to make sure the compare my local changed file with remote repo code. Also how can I take the latest code directly from the remote repo.. Help would be really appreciated as i am in a fix

Comment: 1. Right click a file/project->Compare With->Branch, Tag or Reference...->Remote Tracking-><your remote branch>. 2. Right click->Team>Repository->Pull

Comment: This is what i am using from first.. and still the dirty sign doesnt go.. i am not sure if thats the bug with egit version.. i am using 4.0 version..

Comment: Dirty sign is when there are changes relative to your *local* repository.